# Ошибки при отладке

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, события

Очень нужна помощь! Попытался сделать программу на Visual Basic по уроку из интернета, т.к. сам в программировании мало что понимаю и только учусь.  Во время отладки что-то пошло не так... Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить эти ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx

```
AddHandler mrButton.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf MyButtonClickEventHandler)
```